# Reverse order lines of data at a parent tag level (GPX data)

Tags: xml, gpx

I just went on a hiking trip and used a Garmin to track my GPS route, heart rate & cadence.  I have imported this into the Garmin Portal and that is all working perfectly fine.

The only problem is that it only recorded me from getting A to B (but not back from B to A) - due to the battery running out.

I am hoping to manually add these lines into the code - and I need to basically re-order all the lines of code but at a 'parent tag' level.

Here is a snippet of the code which contains 3 entries.

These are broken up at the  level, and I need to re-order these from 1,2,3 to 3,2,1.

What is the best way to do this?  I have 30,000 lines of code so definitely can't be done manually.

Cheers!

```
<trkpt lat="-44.5103318989276885986328125" lon="168.74328752048313617706298828125">
        <ele>372</ele>
        <time>2016-11-13T21:40:02.000Z</time>
        <extensions>
          <ns3:TrackPointExtension>
            <ns3:hr>89</ns3:hr>
            <ns3:cad>0</ns3:cad>
          </ns3:TrackPointExtension>
        </extensions>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="-44.5103318989276885986328125" lon="168.74328735284507274627685546875">
        <ele>372</ele>
        <time>2016-11-13T21:40:03.000Z</time>
        <extensions>
          <ns3:TrackPointExtension>
            <ns3:hr>88</ns3:hr>
            <ns3:cad>0</ns3:cad>
          </ns3:TrackPointExtension>
        </extensions>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="-44.51031404547393321990966796875" lon="168.743350803852081298828125">
        <ele>371.600006103515625</ele>
        <time>2016-11-13T21:40:12.000Z</time>
        <extensions>
          <ns3:TrackPointExtension>
            <ns3:hr>88</ns3:hr>
            <ns3:cad>46</ns3:cad>
          </ns3:TrackPointExtension>
        </extensions>
      </trkpt>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to do it.

I used an online XML to CSV converter which broken down the tags to multiple CSV files based on the tag level.

The number of rows was exactly the same for the level of detail that I wanted - so I just copied the columns next to each other - and it was all there in a tabular format for me.

So then I did an easy reverse order and had my result :)